# Blank White Screen Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-5

I created a new Controller `UsersController` and set the routes as mentioned below . Now I am trying to access this URL `( http://localhost/ecom/users/signin )` but it is showing nothing but a blank white screen. There is nothing in console and source of this page.I am using Resource Controller and Laravel 5.2.

***PS: If anything needed more just mention in comments.***

**Routes.php**

```
Route::resource('users', 'UsersController');

Route::get('users/signin', 'UsersController@getSignin');
Route::get('users/newaccount', 'UsersController@getSignup');
```

**StoreController.php:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use View;
class UsersController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return View::make('users.newaccount');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), User::$rules);

        if($validator->passes()){
            $user = new User;
            $user->name = Input::get('name');
            $user->email = Input::get('email');
            $user->password = Input::get('password');
            $user->save();
            return Redirect::to('users/signin')->with('message','Thank you for creating new account.Sign in now');
        }
        return Redirect::to('users/newaccount')->with('message','Something went wrong!')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    }

    public function getSignin(){
        return View::make('users.signin');
    }


    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
    public function getSignout(){
        Auth::logout();
        return Redirect::to('users/signin')->with('message','Signouted!');
    }

    /*public function postSignin(){
        if(Auth::attempt(array('name' => Input::get('name'), 'email' => Input::get('email'), 'password'=> 'Input::get('password')))){
            return Redirect::to('/')->with('message','Thanks for signin');
        }
        return Redirect::to('users/singin')->with('message','Was Incorrect DATA!');
    } */


}
```

**Signin View:**

```
     {!! Form::open(array('url' => 'users/signin' , 'method' => 'post')) !!} 

                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="username">User Name:</label>
                            <input type="username" class="form-control" name="name" id="name">
                          </div>

                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="username">Password:</label>
                            <input type="username" class="form-control" name="password" id="name">
                          </div>

                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign IN</button>
   {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: If you put `dd("a");` in getSignin(), does it print something?

Comment: naa it prints nothing just blank screen!

Comment: So, getSignin() is never called. Are the other functions working normally?

Comment: http://localhost/ecom/users/create this is working fine ! Fetching form for newaccount route.

Comment: There is probably a bug in your code, but that can not be displayed. Have you properly set the rights of the 'storage' folder?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/2951316/can-celik This user comment was perfect I don't know why his comment is removed or may be he removed it ! ALL I did was just put the Resource Controller below the get controllers .

Comment: @Marten how to do that I am not familiar with that.

Comment: @LaravelWarrior for Linux and Mac OS: open your terminal, go to your project root and type: chmod -R 755 storage

Comment: @Marten I am using Windows 10 .

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why the comment is got deleted but you can move your routes above the resources, and it should work.

```
Route::get('users/signin', 'UsersController@getSignin');
Route::get('users/newaccount', 'UsersController@getSignup');

Route::resource('users', 'UsersController');
```

Answer (score 0):

In your route put

```
Route::get('users/signin', 'UsersController@getSignin');
Route::get('users/newaccount', 'UsersController@getSignup');
```

over

```
Route::resource('users', 'UsersController');
```

like this

```
Route::get('users/signin', 'UsersController@getSignin');
Route::get('users/newaccount', 'UsersController@getSignup');
Route::resource('users', 'UsersController');
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is hella old but I think its because you are calling the Validator, Redirect and Auth classes without using it at the top...

add:

```
use Validator;
use Auth;
use Response;
```

to the top of your controller.

Answer (score 0):

Check .htaccess.
`Options +ExecCGI
    addhandler x-httpd-php5-cgi .php
    Options -MultiViews
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]
    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    #RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>`